# Unable to create two-way table in excel from powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I want to create two way table in excel by exporting object from powershell. I am able to create a table in powershell. 
The code as shown below:

```
class sampleClass {
    [String] $var1
    [String] $var2
    [Bool] $boolVar

    sampleClass([String] $var1, [String] $var2, [Bool] $boolVar)
    {
        $this.var1 = $var1
        $this.var2 = $var2
        $this.boolVar = $boolVar
    }

    [String] ToString()
    {
        return $this.var1 + ": " + $this.var2 + ": " + $this.boolVar
    }
}

$s1 = [sampleClass]::new("Comp1", "S1", $false)
$s2 = [sampleClass]::new("Comp2", "S2", $true)
$s3 = [sampleClass]::new("Comp1", "S2", $false)
$s4 = [sampleClass]::new("Comp2", "S1", $false)

$s = @()
$s += $s1
$s += $s2    
$s += $s3
$s += $s4
$s | Export-Csv .\out.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The output for above code is as shown below:

[image]

But the output that I want is not that, but as shown below:

[image]

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

This code may be your best bet:

```
function Transpose-Object
{ [CmdletBinding()]
  Param([OBJECT][Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $TRUE)]$InputObject)

  BEGIN
  { # initialize variables just to be "clean"
    $Props = @()
    $PropNames = @()
    $InstanceNames = @()
  }

  PROCESS
  {
    if ($Props.Length -eq 0)
    { # when first object in pipeline arrives retrieve its property names
            $PropNames = $InputObject.PSObject.Properties | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
            # and create a PSCustomobject in an array for each property
            $InputObject.PSObject.Properties | %{ $Props += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{Property = $_.Name} }
        }

        if ($InputObject.Name)
        { # does object have a "Name" property?
            $Property = $InputObject.Name
        } else { # no, take object itself as property name
            $Property = $InputObject | Out-String
        }

        if ($InstanceNames -contains $Property)
        { # does multiple occurence of name exist?
        $COUNTER = 0
            do { # yes, append a number in brackets to name
                $COUNTER++
                $Property = "$($InputObject.Name) ({0})" -f $COUNTER
            } while ($InstanceNames -contains $Property)
        }
        # add current name to name list for next name check
        $InstanceNames += $Property

    # retrieve property values and add them to the property's PSCustomobject
    $COUNTER = 0
    $PropNames | %{
        if ($InputObject.($_))
        { # property exists for current object
            $Props[$COUNTER] | Add-Member -Name $Property -Type NoteProperty -Value $InputObject.($_)
        } else { # property does not exist for current object, add $NULL value
            $Props[$COUNTER] | Add-Member -Name $Property -Type NoteProperty -Value $NULL
        }
            $COUNTER++
    }
  }

  END
  {
    # return collection of PSCustomobjects with property values
    $Props
  }
}
```

It will allow you to turn you columns into rows and then export the object. Use like this:

```
$s | Transpose-Object | Export-Csv .\out.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: My powershell says: Transpose-Object : The term 'Transpose-Object' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program.

Comment: Sorry @User1230321 I should hav specified that this code is not automatically included in PowerShell. You will have to either copy and paste the code into your PowerShell console or into a file and run it. Once the code has been run, you will be able to call Transpose-Function.

Comment: My mistake, Transpose-Object is a user-defined function. This just transposes the object. My requirement is not that. I want $var1 values should come vertically, $var2 values in horizontally(Graph-like). Your code displays the $var1 and $var2 values both horizontally. I cannot put the screenshot here.